# inconsistancy in writing image to hardware in android

Tags: android

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to create a bitmap in a directory on my phone. However it doesn't always work and never seems to work right away. After running if I look in the directory it wont be there, I have to fiddle around in other folders and keep refreshing before it shows up, often it doesn't even show up at all. I do not understand this, any help or insight would be very much appreciated, thanks

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);

    try {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDirectory/" + "test.png");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy image" + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting some Exception at some of those tries?

Comment: No, I never get an exception, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: You are trying to create the file without having created the /myDirectory/ folder first, so it may fail to create your file. You must check the return value of f.createNewFile();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason someone comes across this with a similar problem, I found out the solution. For whatever reason the file wont show up until I disconnect the phone from the USB cable. The second I do the files show up.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer to your own question. When you can, please accept it so others know this question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the file without having created the /myDirectory/ folder first, so it may fail to create your file. Also, you must check the return value of `f.createNewFile()`, because it will return false if the file already exists. For really checking if the file exists, use `f.exists()` instead.

So, if you change your code to:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.i("COMPRESSED Bitmap", " "+myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes));

            try {
                File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDirectory/");
                Log.i("Created external folder successfully", " "+directory.mkdirs());
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDirectory/" + "test.png");
                Log.i("Created external file successfully", " "+f.createNewFile() + " file exists "+ f.exists());
                if(f.exists()){
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("MyActivity", "Was unable to copy image" + e.toString());
            }
```

It will only write to the file if it already exists. I tested it and the file is always there, and is replaced by another if you execute the code a second or third time.

Comment: Thats not it, the directory has already been created. It must just be something specific with my phone, because it works sometimes and other times not at all. Sometimes it works, but the file only shows up several minutes after I run it. Thank you for taking the time to help tho, I do appreciate it very much